# How do I retrieve all "open with" file actions per API?

Tags: scripts, nautilus

I'd like to expose Ubuntu's File-Manager actions in my application (per file).

In Windows you'd have to parse the registry (fairly simple) but I have no idea about Debian or Ubuntu. I don't mind the programming effort and I would love to know about potential shortcuts (shell commands). Is there something like a Platform-API or should I just starting looking at the Nautilus source code? I am guessing there maybe is a mime-mapping somewhere and I could dump it with gnome-conf.

Thanks, any hint is welcome.

Comment: What actions do you want to use in your program?

Comment: actually only 'open-with' actions but when looking at the nautilus-extra-action package, I'd love to get them too. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `open-with` Nautilus uses [GTK](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/) and [GIO](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/):

GTK provides the [GtkAppChooser](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkAppChooser.html) interface and its implementations to be used in a GUI.

On a lower level there's GIO with things like [g_file_query_default_handler ()](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-query-default-handler) to get the default application for a file, or [g_app_info_get_all_for_type ()](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GAppInfo.html#g-app-info-get-all-for-type) to get all registered apps for given a MIME type.

Once you have the [GAppInfo](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GAppInfo.html) for a app you can use [g_app_info_launch ()](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GAppInfo.html#g-app-info-launch) to open a file with that application.

Depending on what programming language you are using there may be better docs, like the [Python GObject Introspection API Reference](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/)

For the shell there's [xdg-open](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html) to open a file with the default application, and [xdg-mime](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xdg-mime.1.html) to do things with MIME types.

If you want to know all the details about MIME handling on Linux see [Shared MIME-info Database](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/latest/) and [Association between MIME types and applications](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.html)

---

`nautilus-extra-action` contains little programs (often shell scripts) for the [Nautilus-Actions](http://www.nautilus-actions.org/) extension. To use them your program needs to implement something like Nautilus-Actions, too.

Comment: plain awesome answer! thanks a lot, the Python API will do it, its for an nodejs/js based desktop file-manager.